# Rendering only the edges in Blender 2.6x - wireframe with thicker lines

Tags: blender

I can't figure out how to render only the edges of my object ( mesh ) with thicker lines, someone know how to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do it:

http://opendimension.org/blender_en/line_drawings.php

---

Generally speaking, quite often in 3D programs there's either a specific type of material you can make Or the program has a feature to make 2D line drawing out of your 3D object. Or a separate plugin.. Or both..

To be a little more specific:
The other one is actual rendering technique where as the other one generates the lines from your 3D object. Those lines you can Export and Import to vector programs even..

Answer (score 0):

That depends on which render engine you are using. Blender has "blender render" - the internal render engine; and "cycles" - the cycles render engine;.

- Internal - in edit mode select the desired edges and pres ctrl+E and slick "mark freestyle edge". Then in the properties window enable "freestyle" then go to "render layers" panel and under the "freestyle" option select only "edges". And there you can udjust the color, thickness etc..